# Interaction between domain/range and universal property restriction in OWL

Tags: owl, semantic-web, semantics, inference

In the contrived example below, I have a class `:Car` and an object property `:hasCarType`. In the definition of `:Car`, I want to specify a universal property restriction on `:hasCarType` using the class `:CarType`.

Intuitively, I also thought it made sense to say that `:hasCarType` had a domain of `:Car` and a range of `:CarType`.

However, if I say **either** `:hasCarType rdfs:domain :Car` or `:hasCarType rdfs:range :CarType`, I get unwanted inferences. Namely, **every** class in the ontology is inferred to be a subclass of the class expression `'has car type' only CarType`. If I remove the domain/range (or, say, remove the domain and change the range to something else, e.g., `:hasCarType rdfs:range skos:Concept`), then the unwanted inferences disappear (i.e., the only subclass of the class expression is `:Car`).

What explains this interaction between domain/range and universal property restriction? The default explanations in Protégé aren't particularly illuminating. Example:

```
Explanation for: Appellation SubClassOf 'has car type' only CarType
1) 'has car type' Range CarType
```

Here are the results in Protégé using the HermiT reasoner:

[image: Screenshot of the DL query widget in Protégé showing results for the class expression has car type only CarType]

```
@prefix : <urn:example/> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> .

:hasCarType rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
            rdfs:domain :Car ;
            rdfs:range :CarType ;
            rdfs:label "has car type" .

:CarType rdf:type owl:Class ; rdfs:subClassOf skos:Concept .

:Car rdf:type owl:Class ;
     owl:equivalentClass [ owl:intersectionOf ( :FourWheeledVehicle
                                                :MotorVehicle
                                                [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                                                  owl:onProperty :hasCarType ;
                                                  owl:allValuesFrom :CarType
                                                ]
                                              ) ;
                           rdf:type owl:Class
                         ] ;
     rdfs:label "Car" .

:car1 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
               :Car ;
      :name [ rdf:type :Appellation ;
              :content "My car"
            ] .
```

Comment: a range axiom is a global restriction, you can rewrite it as `Thing SubClassOf hasCarType only CarType`. That obviously also makes all subclasses of `Thing` following the restriction.

Comment: Not that I understand why this is an issue for you - it doesn't hurt in my opinion - but, indeed you could also make it a local statement only if you write `Car SubClassOf hasCarType only CarType` and omit the range axiom. But as I said, this is a common axiom, it'S only consequence in practice is the inference of indiviuals used as value of the property belonging to the range class.

Comment: @UninformedUser Ah, got it. It's not an issue--just wanted to understand the behavior, and I hadn't grokked the global restriction. Thanks!